# How to add my own file association into the "Open with" context menu?

Tags: c++, winapi, wix, windows-installer

Say, if I right-click a file and then go to "Open with" menu, it will show a submenu, similar to this one:

[image]

How can I add my own program to that "Open with" list?

PS. Note that in this case *I do not need* to create an association with a particular file extension (that a user normally double-clicks to open.)

PS2. I technically need this done from an MSI installer (I'm using WiX) but if someone can suggest APIs or registry to set up I can do this from a custom action as well, if MSI/WiX doesn't directly support it.

Comment: Please refer following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Try this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166549.aspx

Comment: This is the way file extensions work when created with Windows Installer, I recommend you just try it with whatever tool you're using to build MSI files. It removes them successfully too without screwing up the other associations at uninstall time.

Comment: @PhilDW: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I don't want to change the existing file association though, just the "Open with" one. Any idea how to do this with MSI/WiX?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov: Thanks. That's what it seems like I need to do in a custom action for the installer (with a C++ code.)

Comment: There's an example here with the Progid http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/beyond-files

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer from [this](http://coding.indvikleren.dk/file-associations-in-windows#TOC-Open-With---Select-Default-Program...) and [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-unassociate-remove-or-delete-programs-from-open-with-or-recommended-programs-list/) articles.

Say, if I was making a "*Text Zapper*" app and wanted to associate it to "Open With" `.txt` files. Here's a pseudo-markup for the WiX (MSI) layout. It basically defines the registry keys that need to be set. (Note that it doesn't define the `.txt` extension default association for the app.)

```
<?define ProgId = "Text.Zapper.1" ?>
<?define GuiAppExeName = "txtzpr.exe" ?>
<?define ProductThis = "Text Zapper" ?>
<?define AppDescr = "Wonderful Text Zapper Application" ?>


<Component Id='IdTextZapper' Guid='*'>
  <File Id='IdTextZapperExe' Name='$(var.GuiAppExeName)' DiskId='1' Source='$(var.Srctxtzpr)' KeyPath='yes' />

  <!-- Extend the "open with" Windows Explorer function -->
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\$(var.ProgId)" Value="$(var.ProductThis)" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\$(var.GuiAppExeName)" Name="FriendlyAppName" Value="$(var.ProductThis)" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\$(var.GuiAppExeName)\shell\open" Name="FriendlyAppName" Value="$(var.ProductThis)" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\$(var.GuiAppExeName)\shell\open\command" Value='"[INSTALLDIR]$(var.GuiAppExeName)" "%1"' Type="string" />

  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\My Company\Text Zapper\Capabilities" Name="ApplicationDescription" Value="$(var.AppDescr)" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications" Name="$(var.ProductThis)" Value="SOFTWARE\My Company\Text Zapper\Capabilities" Type="string" />

  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\.txt\OpenWithProgIDs" Name="$(var.ProgId)" Value="" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\.txt\OpenWithList\$(var.GuiAppExeName)" Value="" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\$(var.GuiAppExeName)\SupportedTypes" Name=".txt" Value="" Type="string" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\My Company\Text Zapper\Capabilities\FileAssociations" Name=".txt" Value="$(var.ProgId)" Type="string" />

</Component>
```