# Windows: How to associate developed software with a file type for context menu "open with"?

Tags: windows

I'm not a Windows developer and my knowledge of the OS is very limited.

I wanted to write a very simply image viewer software for the Windows OS because such a thing doesn't seem to exist but we have such tools for Linux and they work well.

I am now at the stage where I have something working. But I have no idea how to "install the software program I have written" so that I can associate it with file types such as jpeg and other image files.

I have written this program in C++ although that probably isn't particularly important information.

The point being I am left with an executable file and no idea what to do with it.

I guess the first step to "install" it would be to create a directory in `C:\Program Files\` and simply move the file there, although I'm sure I can do some research and figure out how to write an MSI installer to do that.

Where I become stuck is on other things, like how to create a start menu entry. (Desktop shortcut is easy it's just a link, moved to the users Desktop folder?) And then how to get a right click entry for file types such as PNG bmp and jpeg. (So that "open with" "my program" works)

I tried doing an internet search for this kind of thing but really didn't know what to search for. Can anyone offer me any advice on this or point me in the right direction?

Or is this perhaps the kind of thing I would just get an MSI to do everything for me?

Comment: pretty sure you do this by modifying some registry keys. I will try to get more info. Edit: Here is a link: https://superuser.com/questions/1303165/editing-the-open-with-menu-in-windows-10. If you feel fine editing the registry keys in your code, you could do that. Edit 2: For WIX MSI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831989/how-to-add-my-own-file-association-into-the-open-with-context-menu/22875613

Comment: @KetZoomer I thought it might be a registry thing... I'll try and do some searching myself, this must be quite a common thing for Windows devs to do so the info must be out there somewhere

Comment: Lots of applications do seem to do this. The second I sent should work it you are making the MSIs with WIX MSI, https://wixtoolset.org/. If you aren't making the with WIX MSI, you should.

Comment: *"I wanted to write a very simply image viewer software for the Windows OS because such a thing doesn't seem to exist"* - There's IrfanView. Or TotalCommander's standard lister.

Comment: @IInspectable On Linux we have things like the EyeOfMate image viewer, which is a lot more minimal than IrfanView which is a smaller version of photoshop

Comment: IrfanView is an image viewer. Are you confusing this with Paint.NET? Now if *"minimal"* is a feature to you go with Total Commander. I use its lister for just about any document, including image files. It's literally just a window and two scaling modes.

Answer (score -2):

For adding a Start Menu entry, you'd need to write a link into C:\ .ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.

There you can add just the link to your application or put it in it's own folder. As for the Context Menu entries, there are two options: Adding it manually (But my guess is that you want your installer to do so) by selecting the exe or by modifying the registry.

Comment: There is a reason you cannot comment and it gives you no permission to put comments here in the Answer section. Please delete this.